# Python game, error

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a game for homework, called "FizzBuzz"
I don't know why, but the game isn't working properly, when I enter the correct number I get the error message. I've some suspicion that it's to do with the

```
if b=="x" and c.lower() not in "y":
```

line, as when I change the case of the answer I get different results. I've tried diagnosing the problem but haven't found any success.

(Tips on how I can shorten/make the code more efficient, are appreciated)

```
print("FizzBuzz")
a,b=0,1
while True:
    a+=1
    if a%3==0 and a%5!=0:
        b="Fizz"
    elif a%3!=0 and a%5==0:
        b="Buzz"
    elif a%15==0:
        b="FizzBuzz"
    else:
        b=a
    if a%2!=0:
        print("Comp:",b)
    c=input("You: ")
    if b=="Fizz" and c.lower() not in "f":
        print("You're Wrong, you got up to",a,"points.\n")
        a=0
    elif b=="Buzz" and c.lower() not in "b":
        print("You're Wrong, you got up to",a,"points.\n")
        a=0
     elif b=="FizzBuzz" and c.lower() not in ("f","b"):
        print("You're Wrong, you got up to",a,"points.\n")
        a=0
    else:
        print("Correct\n")
        a+=1
```

Comment: I think you want `"f" not in c.lower():`. Is it?

Comment: Can you add some sample input/output? Like what are you giving as input and what are you expecting as output? And on which case, your code doesn't work? Is it giving any error message? Edit your question with those additional information.

Comment: I'm currently recoding the game.

Answer (score 0):

After recoding I got the game working with an extra function that made the user/computer goes random (2 in a row being max for Comp).

```
import random
print("FizzBuzz")
a,b=1,1
while True:
    d=random.randint(0,2)
    if d==0 and a==1:
        d=1
    for i in range (d):
        if a%15==0:
            b="FizzBuzz"
        elif a%3==0:
            b="Fizz"
        elif a%5==0:
            b="Buzz"
        else:
            b=a
        print("Comp:",b)
        a+=1
    c=input("You: ")
    if a%15==0 and "zb" not in c.lower():
        print("You're Wrong, you got up to",a,"points.\n")
        a=0
    elif a%3==0 and "f" not in c.lower():
        print("You're Wrong, you got up to",a,"points.\n")
        a=0
    elif a%5==0 and "b" not in c.lower():
        print("You're Wrong, you got up to",a,"points.\n")
        a=0
    elif c.isdigit() == False:
        print("You're Wrong, you got up to",a,"points.\n")
        a=0
    else:
        print("Correct\n")
    a+=1
```

Comment: Please use meaningful names. Those `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` don't tell the reader of the code anything about their purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code below.

In the next case provide at least a link to the description of a game.
Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz

```
print("FizzBuzz")
a, b = 0, 1
while True:
    a += 1
    print "a = {}".format(a)

    if a % 3 == 0 and a % 5 != 0:
        b = "Fizz"
    elif a % 3 != 0 and a % 5 == 0:
        b = "Buzz"
    elif a % 3 == 0 and a % 5 == 0:
        b = "FizzBuzz"
    else:
        b = a

    if a % 2 != 0:
        print("Comp:", b)
        continue

    c = input("You: ")

    if b == "Fizz" and ("f" not in c.lower()):
        print("1 You're Wrong, you got up to", a, "points.\n")
        a = 0
    elif b == "Buzz" and ("b" not in c.lower()):
        print("2 You're Wrong, you got up to", a, "points.\n")
        a = 0
    elif b == "FizzBuzz" and (("f" not in c.lower()) and ("b" not in c.lower())):
        print("3 You're Wrong, you got up to", a, "points.\n")
        a = 0
    else:
        print("Correct")
```

Comment: I think I like the one I posted below, alot more.